# PHP Paypal integration testing environment

Tags: php, debugging, testing, paypal, integration

I'm working on website integration with PayPal online payments. I did it before and i know it can be a cumbersome task, especially debugging and testing.

I'm developing on localhost (XAMPP, LAMPP) and I need to upload every time to testing server (on shared hosting) even after small change to be able to test it.

I wonder are there any best practices or ready environments, servers, solutions or phpunits to improve workflow ?

Comment: Why do you need to keep uploading it exactly?

Comment: Because my localhost is unavailable from the world.

Comment: Just set up a firewall rule on your router that allows external access then.

Comment: I'm working in two locations. The first one has internet connection with dynamic IP - I could overcome this with dynDNS but in the second one - more important - i cannot do this due to security policy.

Comment: Well in that case you could use a file browser type FTP system, such as the one Windows' provides built-in. This means you can easily drag files into a folder to upload.